# Run a binary file with shared object dependencies on NodeJS / Express server

Tags: node.js, shell, express, binary, child-process

I'm using NodeJS [childprocess](https://nodejs.org/api/child_process.html) to run shell commands on NodeJS / Express server (localhost). Everything goes well with basic shell commands like 'ls' (from NodeJS documentation):

```
const { spawn } = require('child_process');
const ls = spawn('ls', ['-lh', '/usr']);

ls.stdout.on('data', (data) => {
console.log(`stdout: ${data}`);
});

ls.stderr.on('data', (data) => {
console.log(`stderr: ${data}`);
});

ls.on('close', (code) => {
console.log(`child process exited with code ${code}`); 
});
```

Now, what I need to do is **run a binary file that has shared object dependencies**. The objects are located inside server folder *'public/libraries'*. I've tried to modify the previous with

```
const runBinary = spawn('/path/to/binary/file', ['-someoption', 'public/libraries']);
```

The error message is *'error while loading shared libraries ... no such file or directory'*, meaning the shared objects are not found. I have no idea how to

1) tell 'runBinary' the location of the folder of shared objects, and then

2) run the binary successfully to create output in console.

I have all the necessary tools installed to run the binary in a Bash shell and have tested it works as it should.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can fix this by setting the environment variable `LD_LIBRARY_PATH` to the absolute path of your `public/libraries` directory.

Something like this:

```
spawn('/path/to/binary/file', ['-someoption'],
      {env: {LD_LIBRARY_PATH: '/path/to/public/libraries'}})
```

Comment: @R.Järvinen: You're welcome.  You can accept this answer by clicking the checkmark on the left.  Welcome to Stack Overflow.